# How to sort json according to my requirement

Tags: java, json

I am having one list.i am converting this list as a json String object and send it ui.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
     String jsonString = gson.toJson(environmentnamesList);
     return jsonString;
```

This is my json object.

```
[{"id":3272,"company_name":"HCL - Demo"},{"id":3255,"company_name":"IBM1 - Test"},{"id"
:3257,"company_name":"ECO1 - Development"},{"id":3253,"company_name":"MindSpace - Development"
},{"id":3256,"company_name":"ABC - Demo"},{"id":3258,"company_name":"CDF - Test"},
{"id":3205,"company_name":"FGR - Production"},{"id":3208,"company_name":"RFGGDDF - Production"
}]
```

Now i want to sort json object:

### Requirement:

1)If my comapny_name contains Production(RFGGDDF - Production) give first priority for that

2)If my company_name contains Development(MindSpace - Development) give second priority.

3)If my company_name contains Demo (ABC - Demo) give 3rd priority

4)Id my company_name contains Test(IBM1 - Test) give 4th priority:

i want output like this:

```
[{"id":3205,"company_name":"FGR - Production"},{"id":3208,"company_name":"RFGGDDF - Production"},
{"id":3257,"company_name":"ECO1 - Development"},{"id":3253,"company_name":"MindSpace - Development"},
{"id":3272,"company_name":"HCL - Demo"},{"id":3256,"company_name":"ABC - Demo"}
,{"id":3258,"company_name":"CDF - Test"},{"id":3255,"company_name":"IBM1 - Test"}]
```

Comment: it's easier for people to help you if they have some relevant **piece of code** to work on - please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: It would also be easier to understand the input and output if you'd format it - one entry per line... Also, you've given 4 conditions... but what if the entry doesn't meet any of those? How would you want to order two companies with names which aren't in your special list?

Comment: i am not have a basic  idea how to sort JSON.

Comment: Surely my json satisfy any one of this conditions and my company names are unique.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to sort environmentnamesList before converting to json. Entries that are inside of that list should be comparable. I.e. implement Comparable interface

Edit 1:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 // TODO: sort environmentnamesList here
 String jsonString = gson.toJson(environmentnamesList);
 return jsonString;

public class EnvironmentItem 
        implements Comparable<EnvironmentItem> {
    public int compareTo(EnvironmentItem item) {
        // TODO compare this & item 
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me detailed

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @virtual-agent-07 that I should sort environments *before* converting to JSON.
There are plenty of ways to do that, I'd suggest to use Google's [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library.
Example:

```
List<Environment> environments = //...
List<String> envTypes = Arrays.asList("Production", "Development", "Demo", "Test");
Ordering<Environment> ordering = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(c -> Iterables.indexOf(envTypes, envType -> c.getCompanyName().contains(envType)));
Collections.sort(environments, ordering);
```

Comment: Ordering<Environment> ordering = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(c -> Iterables.indexOf(envTypes, envType -> c.getCompanyName().contains(envType)));  i am getting so many error for this line

Comment: @mvswetha What kind of errors? As I said, this example uses Guava library, so you need to add it somehow into your project.

Comment: c -> Iterables.indexOf(envTypes, envType -> c.getCompanyName().contains(envType)...........here what is C and what is envType

Comment: `c` is current environment for sorting, `envType` is one of the `envTypes`. This code should work smoothly. Are you using Java 8?

Comment: Ordering<Environment> ordering = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(c -> Iterables.indexOf(envType, envTypes -> c.getCompanyName().contains(envType)));....this one i wrote

Comment: Ok, just replace lambdas with `Function`'s (see the arguments required by `onResultsOf()` method for example)

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
<script>
  angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    var compareData = ["FGR - Production", "RFGGDDF - Production", "ECO1 - Development", "MindSpace - Development", "HCL - Demo", "ABC - Demo", "CDF - Test", "IBM1 - Test"];

   var json = [{"id":3272,"company_name":"HCL - Demo"},{"id":3255,"company_name":"IBM1 - Test"},{"id"
    :3257,"company_name":"ECO1 - Development"},{"id":3253,"company_name":"MindSpace - Development"
    },{"id":3256,"company_name":"ABC - Demo"},{"id":3258,"company_name":"CDF - Test"},
    {"id":3205,"company_name":"FGR - Production"},{"id":3208,"company_name":"RFGGDDF - Production"
    }];

    json.sort(function(objA, objB){
      return compareData.indexOf(objA.company_name) - compareData.indexOf(objB.company_name);
    });
    console.log(json);
  }]);

</script>
```